# Quiero ponerle un numero de registro a una base traida de MongoDB

Tags: nodejs, mongodb

soy novato, mi consulta es: Traigo datos de MongoDb en un una tabla y quiero que me aparezca el numero de registro, se que hay una funcion y que es algo muy simple de hacer pero como aclare soy novato en el tema y estoy aprendiendo por que les pido que las respuestan sean desestructuradas y simples. Gracias

```
function pedirUsuarios (req, res){
  req.app.locals.titular=true
      User.find({}, (err, socios)=>{
        if (err){
          res.send (err)
        } else{
          res.render("usuarios", {socios, titular:req.app.locals.titular , usuario: req.session.user})
        }
      }).lean()
     }
```

el html de la tabla:

```
<table class="table table-hover">
       
  <thead>
    <tr class="table-dark">
      <th scope="col">Nº Orden</th>
      <th scope="col">Apellido</th>
      <th scope="col">Nombre</th>
      <th scope="col">Direccion</th>
      <th scope="col">Altura</th>
      <th scope="col">Ciudad</th>
      <th scope="col">Estado</th>
      <th scope="col">CP</th>
      <th scope="col">Email</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  {{#each socios}} 
  <tbody>
    <tr> 
      <th scope="row"></th>
      <td>{{apellidoRegistro}}</td>
      <td>{{nombreRegistro}}</td>
      <td>{{calleRegistro}}</td>
      <td>{{alturaRegistro}}</td>
      <td>{{ciudadRegistro}}</td>
      <td>{{estadoRegistro}}</td>
      <td>{{cpRegistro}}</td>
      <td>{{emailRegistro}}</td>
    </tr>
    {{/each}}
  </tbody>
</table>
```

y la tabla:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

yo quiero que en orden aparezca: 1  2   3   4   5

Comment: que tal con `{{@index}}`?

Comment: Si!genio!!!! Lo único que empieza del 0 hay como hacer para que empiece del 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para eso debes crear un helper de handlebars:

```
var Handlebars = require('handlebars');

Handlebars.registerHelper("masUno", function(value, options)
{
    return parseInt(value) + 1;
});
```

Y luego lo usas como

```
{{masUno @index}}
```

Aqui un ejemplo funcional:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/4.7.7/handlebars.min.js"></script>

<script>
  // Compilamos el template
  var datos = [10, 20, 30];

  Handlebars.registerHelper("masUno", function(value, options)
  {
      return parseInt(value) + 1;
  });

  var template = Handlebars.compile(`{{#each datos}}
   - {{masUno @index}}: {{this}}   
  {{/each}}`);
  
  
  // Mostramos el resultado
  console.log(template({ datos }));
</script>
```

Comment: Ahí lo hago! Y te digo! Una consulta más porque en los helpers se usa options?

Comment: La verdad no uso mucho handlebars, no se específicamente para que casos sea util, de igual manera si no lo usas lo puedes quitar de la funcion y dejar solo el value

Comment: Gracias! por la respuesta, funciono! no use options y funciono igual! mil gracias!